# Docker: Apache2 container can not talk to php7.1 container

Tags: php, docker-compose, apache2.4

I have Apache2 and PHP-FPM running in two separate containers. Both containers run OK, but I'm unable to process php files. When I navigate to a php file the browsers responds with 'File not found.' Looking in the apache error log I get:

```
[Fri Feb 01 09:50:54.894531 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 8:tid 140041300997888] [client 44.82.126.19:65344] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Principally I have been following the setup instructions [here](https://www.cloudreach.com/blog/containerize-this-php-apache-mysql-within-docker-containers/). Searches of other sites show similar setups.

I note that the instructions don't include the apache2 PHP module, but it seems fcgi takes care of this...?

**Some debugging results:**

- I can visit the host IP and render an HTML web page.
- Inside the Apache2 container I can ping the PHPcontainer successfully. So the internal network is working.
- In the PHP container I can run CLI PHP commands successfully.
- I have checked the PHP-FPM config file and "Docker inspect" for the exposure of port 9000. All OK.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.2'
volumes:
  apache2Config:
    external: true
  webContent:
    external: true
  databases:
    external: true

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: './php7.1/'
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
    image: php7.1.26-fpm:1.0
    restart: always
    container_name: php
    networks:
      - backend
  web:
    build: ./apache2/
    image: apache2:1.0
    restart: always
    container_name: AOW_apache2Server
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mariadb
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    expose:
     - "80"
     - "81"
     - "443"
     - "8083"
    ports:
     - "80:80/tcp"
     - "81:81"
     - "443:443"
     - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - apache2Config:/mnt/apache2Conf
      - webContent:/var/www
  mariadb:
    build: ./mariaDB/
    image: mariadb_10.4.0
    container_name: mariaDB_10.4.0
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*****
    volumes:
      - databases:/var/lib/mysql
```

**Apach2 config:**

```
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
ServerName aow

Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn mod_rewrite.c:trace2

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

#Allow access to the /usr/share directory. phpmyadmin is located in here.
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#Allow access to the www directory. Mediawiki source files are in here.
#Directory listing is disabled, but following symLinks is allowed.
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**Apache2 enabled mods:**

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)

 deflate_module (shared)

 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 file_cache_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 macro_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)

 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)

 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

**000-default.conf contents:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Proxy .php requests to port 9000 of the php-fpm container
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/$1

    ServerAdmin <<REMOVED>>
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just noticed that the DocumentRoot is different to the path in ProxyPassMatch. Not sure if this matters, but can't test it till Monday. The PHP file I'm calling is in both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an access issue. Have you made sure that the PHP/FPM container has access to the directory Apache is pointing to?